# How to calculate number of perfect matchings?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, inclusion-exclusion, matching-theory, derangements

Assume that we have a bipartite graph called $G$ such that $G=(X, Y)$ and we have $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$.

For each $1\leq i\leq n$, $x_i$ is adjacent to $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ \ $\{y_i\}$.
What is the number of perfect matchings in this graph?

I personally thought that maybe we can solve it recursively, and I have just compute for small $n$’s like 3 and 4. I got 2 for $n=3$ and 9 for $n=4$.

Comment: Have you heard of derangements?

Comment: This is one for [the in-and-out-formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: @bof I thought it might be solved with the in and out formula, but I got confused with the calculations

Comment: Did you work out $n=4$ with brute force, or the in-and-out formula?

Comment: @bof I just calculated it manually

Comment: Since you're having trouble applying the IAOF in the general cases, why don't you tryusing it on those small cases and see if you get the same answer? And then try it for $n=5$; you should get $44$. (You gotta walk before you can run.)

Comment: @bof Thanks for your help. I have to say that I know how to work with IAOF, but does this mean that any one who has worked with something, can solve all of the problems about that subject? And I am also looking for a good solution, it might not necessarily be solved by IAOF, but I’ll definitely try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will work out the case $n=4$ with the in-and-out formula. I think you will see how to generalize it.

Let $H$ be the *complete* bipartite graph with vertex sets $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and $\{y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4\}$. It has all $16$ edges $x_iy_j$ and $4!=24$ perfect matchings, but we only want to count the perfect matchings that don't use any of the edges $x_iy_i$.

Let $E$ be the set of all $24$ perfect matchings in $H$, and let $A_i$ be the set of perfect matchings that use the edge $x_iy_i$. The set we want to count is $E\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4)$.  By the in-and-out formula,
$$|E\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4)|$$
$$=|E|-|A_1|-|A_2|-|A_3|-|A_4|$$
$$+|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_3|+|A_1\cap A_4|+|A_2\cap A_3|+|A_2\cap A_4|+|A_3\cap A_4|$$
$$-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_4|-|A_1\cap A_3\cap A_4|-|A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|$$
$$+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|.$$
Now $|E|=4!$ and $|A_1|=3!$ and $|A_1\cap A_2|=2!$ and $|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|=1!$ and $|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|=0!$, so the mess above evaluates to
$$\binom404!-\binom413!+\binom422!-\binom431!+\binom440!$$
$$=\frac{4!}{0!}-\frac{4!}{1!}+\frac{4!}{2!}-\frac{4!}{3!}+\frac{4!}{4!}$$
$$=24-24+12-4+1=\boxed{9}.$$
Can you take it from here? For $n=5$ you should get 
$$\frac{5!}{0!}-\frac{5!}{1!}+\frac{5!}{2!}-\frac{5!}{3!}+\frac{5!}{4!}-\frac{5!}{5!}$$
$$=120-120+60-20+5-1=\boxed{44}.$$
If you don't like the way I did it, just look up **derangements** on Wikipedia or something.